# Differences between SQLAlchemy Relationships

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Being new to SQLAlchemy and SQL, the relationships in SQLAlchemy is confusing to me.

Is this set of SQLAlchemy model definitions (based on [One-To-Many in the official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many))

```
class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invoices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = relationship("Customer")

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    invoice_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('invoices.id'))
```

identical to

```
class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invoices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    invoice_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('invoices.id'))
    invoice = relationship("Invoice")
```

I have been defining my models using the second approach and it appears to work fine so far. However I am unsure whether this is the correct way to go about setting up relationships.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: `relationship("Invoice")` is for the object side of ORM, `ForeignKey` for the relational.

Answer (score 2):

Each of those models is the same as far as the resulting database tables and columns go. The difference is in how you are using the [`relationship()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) directive that enables the ORM to interact with the foreign key relationship between those tables. I should note that you do not need to create these relationship attributes at all if you don't need / want the extra help from the ORM in interacting with these relationships between tables.

In your first example, you are creating a `customer` attribute for `Invoice` that would enable you to do things like access any and all customers associated with a particular invoice. For example, you could print each customer id associated with a particular invoice.

```
invoice = session.query(Invoice).filter(Invoice.id == 1).first()
for c in invoice.customer:
    print(c.id)
```

In your second example, you are creating an `invoice` attribute for `Customer` that would enable you to do things like access the invoice data associated with a particular customer. For example, you could print the customer's invoice id (this would be more useful if you had other `Invoice` columns not already referenced by foreign key in `Customer`).

```
customer = session.query(Customer).filter(Customer.id == 1).first()
print(customer.invoice.id)
```

In the event that you would like to access these attributes on both sides of the relationship so that you could use the ORM in both of the ways described above (among others), you could use either the `back_populates` or `backref` parameters to connect the two relationships. You can learn more about these options at [Linking Relationships with Backref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref).

```
class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invoices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customers = relationship("Customer", back_populates="invoice")

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    invoice_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('invoices.id'))
    invoice = relationship("Invoice", back_populates="customers")
```